# A question related to the convergence of series in probability

Tags: probability, convergence, probability-inequalities

Let $(X_j)_{j\in \mathbb Z}$ be an strictly stationary sequence of random variables with:
$$E[X_j]=0, \quad E[X_j^2] < \infty$$
I want to show that for each positive $\varepsilon$:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P\left(\max_{1\leq j\leq 2^n}\lvert X_j\rvert>2^{n/2}\varepsilon\right)<\infty.
$$
Note that:
$$
\mathbb P\left(\max_{1\leq j\leq 2^n}\lvert X_j\rvert>2^{n/2}\varepsilon\right)= \mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{2^n} \left[ |X_j| >2^{n/2}\varepsilon\right]\right)\leq \sum_{j=1}^{2^n} \mathbb P\left(  |X_j| >2^{n/2}\varepsilon\right)
$$
By stationarity, we have
$$\sum_{j=1}^{2^n} \mathbb P\left(  |X_j| >2^{n/2}\varepsilon\right)= 2^n \mathbb P\left(  |X_1|>2^{n/2}\varepsilon\right)= 2^n \mathbb P\left(  |X_1|^2>2^{n}\varepsilon^2\right)$$
My initial idea is to use a comparison test (I accept another solution). However, I am unable to finish.

Could you help me finish?

Comment: If $E[X_j]=0$, then most people would assume that $E[X_j]^2=0$ also, and so the second inequality would be unnecessary.. Or did you mean to write $E[X_j^2] < \infty$ (which makes a lot more sense) instead of $E[X_j]^2 < \infty $?

Comment: Can you add the source of this result?

Comment: Please, see the comment of the answer of this question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4719818/an-exercise-on-convergences-involving-a-fixed-realization-of-a-stochastic-proces I spent a few hours thinking about the suggestion the respondent gave me, but I couldn't. I'm afraid it's something very trivial that I'm missing. Since I don't like to take too much time from one respondent, I decided to post this question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To finish the proof, use the equality $E[X_1^2] = \int_0^\infty P[X_1^2 > t]dt$, whence
\begin{align*}
 & E[X_1^2] = \int_0^\infty P[X_1^2 > t]dt \\
\geq & \sum_{n = 1}^\infty
\int_{2^{n - 1}\varepsilon^2}^{2^n\varepsilon^2}P[X_1^2 > t]dt \\
\geq & \sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^{n - 1}\varepsilon^2P[X_1^2 > 2^n\varepsilon^2].
\end{align*}
Linking the summand in the last expression above to the last probability in your post and using the condition $E[X_1^2] < \infty$ finishes the proof.

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/613847/limsup-n-dfracx-nn-0-if-mathbbex-1-infty/613859#613859) applied the similar trick.

Comment: Dear, I had already tried to do this:
$$2^n \mathbb P\left( |X_1|^2>2^{n}\varepsilon^2\right)= \frac{\mathbb E [|X_1|^2]  }{\varepsilon^2}$$
However, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mathbb E [|X_1|^2]  }{\varepsilon^2}$ Does not converge.